# Add element before after its called

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I had one php script in which I am calling one function.

Example SCRIPT:

```
    <div class="main-info">
        <div class="screenshot">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="screenshot-later">
    </div>
```

I want to display

```
<div class="screenshot-later"></div>
```

this div in main-info class where div is

```
<div class="screenshot">
```

I just have rough idea that it can be done using javascript or jQuery.

But didn't know much about it so any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean that you want to reorganize the DOM so the `screenshot-later` div is removed from its initial place and replaces the `screenshot` div inside the `main-info` div?

Comment: say it clearly. what you want to achieve?

Comment: Look at left menu in [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) . There is a whole section of DOM manipulation methods with numerous insertion methods....and examples for each A simple google search would also give you lots of results

Comment: @tedHopp yes as you said

Comment: Wouldn't be easier and cleaner by moving the element from the php code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following using JQuery:

```
$(".main-info").find(".screenshot").replaceWith($(".screenshot-later"));
```

Comment: He wants to remove screenshot-later from its initial place and replace .screenshot, not to append it ti .screenshot...

Comment: True, it seems I haven't understand the question, edited my answer.

Comment: But he wants to remove .screenshot-later from its initial position as well. Please, read my answer...

Comment: The `replaceWith` function can move the element. Read [here](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

Answer (score 0):

Your example `script` contains html inside a php tag. I would be very surprised if that would work. Instead of that I propose

```
<div class="main-info">
    <div class="screenshot">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="screenshot-later">
</div>
```

Make sure you are loading jQuery correctly. You will need a `script` tag for that with the correct path to jQuery. Then, you will need a `function` like this:

```
function handleScreenshotLater() {
    $(.main-info).html($(.screenshot-later).remove());
}
```

and then call the `function` when you want, just make sure that the page was already loaded.

Comment: I know how to add div in php tag...it was just an example script